# MongoDB/PHP doesn't like Russian characters

Tags: php, encoding, mongodb

We're using MongoDB and PHP to handle IPNs from PayPal. The problem is we've had a number of customers from Russia and, try as I might, I can't get MongoDB to store the data correctly.

For example, we had a customer called Юлия with a Russian address with similar formatted characters. If I print this out directly in PHP it displays correctly but if I put it into MongoDB and call it back I just get Ð®Ð»Ð¸Ñ

I've tried various encodings but every time MongoDB seems to return the wrong text. How should I format the text to store these characters in MongoDB and be able to retrieve them? Do I need to convert them to one format for storage and then convert them back again for display?

Comment: Which encoding is the input of your application and which encoding is the output of your application?

Comment: Please add the code where you store into and where you read from MongoDB.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mongo stores all strings as utf-8 and expects them to be delivered as such. Simply convert your data to utf-8 before sending it to mongo and you're set.

Comment: And convert it back to the original encoding after getting in back from Mongo ;)

Comment: Indeed, or simply use utf-8 encoding throughout your app to avoid all that sillyness :p

Comment: I won't call encoding sillyness seriously, however, preferring UTF-8 as encoding for the whole application IO does not sound bad :D

Comment: Indeed. Most mongo drivers do the encoding for you though but apparently PHP is an exception.

Comment: Well PHP itself is not able to differ yet, so knows no encoding internally. How could a driver know then?

Comment: Oh I wasn't implying it should. I know absolutely nothing about PHP ;)